# Differential equation is not working

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve Differential equation, but its not working. Even, if I am using rhs=1, still it does not work. Any idea will help me a lot

```
 DSolve[(486 (-11 + 4 r) h[r] + 
   r (-243 (-22 + 21 r) Derivative[1][h][r] + 
      r (22968 - 3190 I \[Pi] - 12276 r + 2340 I \[Pi] r - 
         3159 r^2 + (3190 - 2340 r) Log[-10 + 9 r] - 
         243 (-11 + 7 r) (h^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r])))/(243 r^3) == 0, 
 h[r], r]
```

Comment: Is there a good reason to expect it to have a computable exact solution?

Comment: Yes, so that I can get the idea of effect of rhs in the result. If I am using rhs=0, it is working perfectly fine

Comment: Maybe you typed two backquote characters instead of two single quotes in the second derivative term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine in version 12

```
lhs = (2 (-\[Mu]1 + \[Mu]2) x[i] Derivative[1][h][
       r])/(a r) - ((\[Lambda]1 - \[Lambda]2) x[
       i] (2 h[r] + r Derivative[1][h][r]))/(a r^2) + ((a \[Mu]1 + 
        r (-\[Mu]1 + \[Mu]2)) x[
       i] (-2 h[r] + 
        r (2 Derivative[1][h][r] + 
           r h''[r])))/(a r^3) + ((a (\[Lambda]1 + \[Mu]1) + 
        r (-\[Lambda]1 + \[Lambda]2 - \[Mu]1 + \[Mu]2)) x[
       i] (-2 h[r] + r (2 Derivative[1][h][r] + r h''[r])))/(a r^3);
rhs[r_] := 
  1/(3 a (k1 - k2)^2 k2 r) q (-(a \[Alpha]1 + 
         r (-\[Alpha]1 + \[Alpha]2)) (3 \[Lambda]1 - 3 \[Lambda]2 + 
        2 \[Mu]1 - 2 \[Mu]2) ((k1 - k2) (a k1 - 2 a k2 + k2 r) - 
        a k1 k2 Log[-a k2] + a k1 k2 Log[-a k1 + k1 r - k2 r]) - 
     1/(a k1 + (-k1 + k2) r) (a (3 \[Lambda]1 + 2 \[Mu]1) + 
        r (-3 \[Lambda]1 + 3 \[Lambda]2 - 2 \[Mu]1 + 
           2 \[Mu]2)) ((k1 - k2)^2 k2 r (a \[Alpha]1 + 
           r (-\[Alpha]1 + \[Alpha]2)) + (a k1 + (-k1 + 
              k2) r) (\[Alpha]1 - \[Alpha]2) ((k1 - k2) (a k1 - 
              2 a k2 + k2 r) - a k1 k2 Log[-a k2] + 
           a k1 k2 Log[-a k1 + k1 r - k2 r]))) x[i];
DSolve[lhs == rhs[r], h[r], r]
```

[image: Figure1]

Comment: Thanks Alex. I had 11.3 version that's why it was not working.